# Help with 3-pin, "Y", circular plug identification

Tags: identification, connector, plug

The plug's outer diameter is 15 mm.
The pins are ~4.5 mm apart.
The pins are under 2 mm thick.

It is from a Kaabo Mantis King GT/Wolf GT. SP17 and M15 are similar, but not the same.
Compared to XLR, the pins are much thinner.

[Here](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005006161224504.html) is the adapter, so I guess at least somebody somewhere is able to get hold of these.

[image: unknown plug]

Comment: That's a weird one. It might help if you tell us what it belongs to.

Comment: Is that an e-bike?

Comment: Probably easier to find a different 3 terminal plug that has pigtails and use that

Comment: What is a "Kaabo Mantis King GT"? Is it a bike or a beard trimmer? Add it into your question.